# ¿Cómo ajustar Height de un Div a medida que se agregan componentes html?

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap-4

Hola tengo el siguiente código *html*

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">                  
                    <div class="container-form-render" id="container-form-render" style="overflow-y:scroll">
                       <!-- Aqui se agregan componentes html -->
                    </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
```

Dentro del contenedor con `id='container-form-render'` se agregan por *js* componentes de tipo text, select,tablas etc son muchos y todos se agregan por *javascript*.

Mi problema es que no logro hacer que ha medida que se vayan agregandos los componentes, el `Height` del contenedor con `id container-form-render` se ajuste y haga scroll vertical, me pasa que se agrega pero el `<div>` tiene `Height 0` pues apenas se ve, sin embargo cuando le pongo:

```
style="height:400px;"
```

Enseguida se ven los componentes y hace scroll vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con esto le dices que  el max, del div es de tantos pixeles y le dices que cuando lo supere que haga scroll sobre el eje y

```
overflow-y:scroll;
 max-height: MAXIMO EN PIXELES  que quieras que se agrende.;
```

Comment: me funciono pero poniendole Height solamente, cuando le pongo max-height no pasa nada